# Automatic sort for excel worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I want to create a to-do list in Excel that automatically sorts the to-do entries in a list, in order of ones to do first (closest deadlines). I would also like a section that shows the tasks for today and another for high-priority tasks coming up within a week.

I have not programmed in Excel before. I know Python and JavaScript, but want an Excel solution that runs inside Excel (maybe using VBA, the Excel programming language).

Is this sort of thing possible in Excel?

Comment: Your question asks if it is possible. Yes. Defining where you prioritize tasks is necessary. It sounds as if you define them by more than just date.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Excel 2007 or later:

1. Define what is "Priority" (Column B in example).
2. Flag those that are due within 1 week `=IF(AND(B2="Priority",C2<NOW()+7),1,"")` in `D2` in example, and copy down.
3. Create a pivot table from `ColumnsA:D` (Report Filter = Priority, Row Labels = Date and Task), filter on Multiple Items: Priority and (blank).
4. Take copy of pivot table, change Report Filter to "Priority Imminent" and filter on "1".
5. Refresh as and when desired.

[image: SU457719 example]