# How to set auto sort on two columns when open the workbook?

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a workbook that we run for weekly reports, however daily we are adding new records also.

Now, I want to know that how could I set auto sorting on two specific columns every time I open the workbook.

*Following are the columns I want to use:*

- Current Work Year End from Old to New (Column D, data begins in row 6).
- Work Status from Z to A (Column J, data begins in row 6).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJIar.png)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1207529/how-can-i-have-data-re-sort-when-a-file-opens shows how to sort-on-opening with a line of VBA code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I have data re-sort when a file opens?](https://superuser.com/questions/1207529/how-can-i-have-data-re-sort-when-a-file-opens)

Answer (score -1):

**To set Auto Sort on desire columns while open the Workbook, you need this Macro(VBA).**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Open()

Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D6"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Sort Key2:=Range("J6"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. Press `Alt+F11` to open VB editor.
2. On top left in `Project Explorer windows` find `ThisWorkbook`.
3. `Double click` it then `Copy & Paste` this Code.
4. `Save` & `Close` the Workbook.

**Note:**

Now, every time you open the Workbook Excel will RUN this code to Sort data on specified Columns.

Comment: Plzz write your concern what is wrong with the code!